# Find index of minimum value for each unique value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, unique, minimum

I have two vectors of the same size:

```
A = [1    2    3    1    2    3];
B = [0.1  1.5  0.2  0.7  0.5  2];
```

I want to get the index of each of the smallest values of B, for each of the unique values in A. In the above example, i would want to know that the smallest value in B for A==1 has index 1,  and the smallest value in B for A==2 has index 5, and so on.

In my actual data, there need not be an even number of 1s, 2s, 3s, etc. We don't know how large the vectors are head of time. Likewise, we don't know the maximum value of A, though it can be assumed that A only contains nonzero integers and that each value to the max is represented (i.e., if it goes to 4, numbers 1-3 must be present).

Here's a function i use to accomplish this right now:

```
function inds = customfunction(A,B)

% Some information about A
unique_values = unique(A);
num_values = length(unique_values);

% loop over unique values of A, adding min indices to inds
inds = zeros(1,num_values);
for i=1:num_values

%   identify instances of current value
    currentvals = A == unique_values(i);

%   set up temporary variable, turn non-instances into NaN
    temp_var = B;
    temp_var(~currentvals) = NaN;

%   get min index of remaining values
    [~, inds(i)] = min(temp_var);
end

end
```

This function just *feels* inefficient, though it does give the correct results. Does anyone know of a more elegant solution?

Comment: I have a feeling the third output of `unique` could help you, but it's not working for me yet

Comment: Refer to the duplicate.  Specifically the last part of the accepted answer.  Once you're there, replace `max` with `min` instead.

Comment: That works! I even nested the two functions for a slick single-file solution.

Comment: @nolanconaway very nice! Glad to have helped!

Comment: @nolanconaway I've rolled back your edit as answers should not be edited in to questions. They should remain separate.

Comment: Apologies for the multiple edits to your post. I initially didn't agree with the edit that @IKavanagh made, but I changed it back because I now agree with him.